# Resolving : " distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: Unable to parse option value to dict: src"

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, setup.py, pyproject.toml

When I want to pip install my own package published on PyPi, I get an error:

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py", line 340, in _parse_dict
      raise DistutilsOptionError(
  distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: Unable to parse option value to dict: src
```

It seems this error is related to `src` in `package_dir` not been correctly parsed in `setup.cfg`. However I am entirely using `pyproject.toml`, I have no `setup.cfg` in my project structure.

This is how I specfiy, the source folder in `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

Comment: I solved it with add a `setup.py` with contents: 
from setuptools import setup
`
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
` 

I dont know why though. Following answers to this question could explain why this solves the problem.